# cocos2d_iphone,how to create a modal dialog with CCLayer? to show people pause, retry,and quit

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I want to create a modal dialog with `CCLayer`,as pause function,show people to retry,resume,or quit.

I had add one sprite to cover main layer,and set the touch is not enable. But the button in main layer also can be touched.
How to do this?
How to show one modal to user?

Comment: Are you trying to add just a pause menu? This is very confusing...

Comment: i mean,pop one CCLayer as modal dialog,and the modal dialog has three buttons allow user to choice.

Answer (score 0):

setting `isTouchEnabled:` disables taouches only to the layer, not to it's children. It means, that if your layer has touch delegate methods, they will not be called when `isTouchEnabled:` is set to `NO`. If you have CCMenu instance or other touchable child, you must change it's `isTouchEnabled:` property separately.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this with a HUD layer. Every game layer I make has a HUD layer overlaid. HUD layer has a `CCMenu` with an pause image to pause the game.

When player pauses the game HUD layer shows another `CCMenu` to restart, exit or resume the game. And the HUD also stores a `BOOL` isPaused. In `ccTouchBegan` (on the game layer) I check if the HUD.isPaused and if so return `NO`, otherwise return `YES`. That solves any unwanted touches in game.